# Can I refer to data in jsonb table if no matching field in cross join table

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have json data in table that I use to insert new data into final table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE musicbrainz.acoustid_track (
    id int NOT NULL,
    created timestamp with time zone DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    gid uuid NOT NULL,
    new_id varchar(30)
);

CREATE TABLE musicbrainz.acoustid_track_json (
    data jsonb
);
```

......
tables loaded
......

The json column `data` is visible in the query and you can refer to it in the `WHERE` clause, e.g.:

```
insert into musicbrainz.acoustid_track 
select id, created, gid, new_id 
from musicbrainz.acoustid_track_json 
cross join jsonb_populate_record(null::musicbrainz.acoustid_track, data);
```

and this works except **acoustid_track_json** can contains new records or replacement records, and this is detemrined by if they have an updated field

e.g

New record

```
{"id":67028798,"gid":"18575a2d-bc9c-48c0-b5d7-f815b97421ed","created":"2020-02-03T00:02:11.315629+00:00"}
```

Updated record

```
{"id":66277512,"gid":"a31e1ecc-af48-4b8f-ba65-de5187a5c9a7","new_id":65603612,"created":"2019-11-17T12:37:49.81505+00:00","updated":"2020-02-03T13:12:58.043985+00:00"}
```

but I cant seem to modify INSERT to refer to updated field, possibly because no updated field in the final table, how do I do this.

Answer (score 0):

The json column `data` is visible in the query and you can refer to it in the `WHERE` clause, e.g.:

```
insert into musicbrainz.acoustid_track 
select id, created, gid, new_id 
from musicbrainz.acoustid_track_json 
cross join jsonb_populate_record(null::musicbrainz.acoustid_track, data)
where data->'updated' is null;
```

Comment: Gives error HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "jsonb_populate_record.created".
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type jsonb
LINE 1: ...ate_record(null::acoustid_track_mbid, data) where data->'upd...

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error, [try it in the fidle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0e868d234ceb7d4fa3de8dca5fb3ed39)